# Resize digital clock

Tags: clock

Is there any way to make my digital clock smaller on my T-Mobile ZTE Zinger cellphone homepage?  In the widget app, it shows 3x2.  I would like to make it 1x1.  There is a white box with dots, but I can't resize it.

Comment: Not all widgets allow resizing, if you see the dots it's probably cause of the launcher that displays them by default but they cannot be moved if the widget has a fixed size. Try installing different clock apps from the Play store, making sure in the description resizable widgets are mentioned.

Comment: Many uneven sizes, like 3x2, cannot be shrunk, only enlarged. There are exceptions, but I don't think the clock is one.

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned by others in the comment that the Clock widget can't be shrinked less than `3x2` size dimensions. You can alternatively try a third party app from the Play Store. Ony such example is,

[1x1 Clock widget](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.github.wakhub.tinyclock) in which you can have clock widgets in multiple sizes with the customization options available within the app. You can find the source code of this app on this [GitHub link](https://github.com/wakhub/tinyclock).

Or if you want analog clock, you could try [Simple Analog Clock - Widget](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.moemoe.tomorrow.myAnalogClock2) from the Playstore to create a 1x1 clock widget.